# unresolved reference pycharm doesn't recognize class under it

Tags: python, python-3.x, pycharm

I have the following problem.

I have something like this

```
class X(models.Model):
    def add_meber(self, user : User <-Error here):
        # code

class User(AbstractUser):
    # Code
```

Pycharm is no the class User when I use the type hint in the class X, there is a way to make this work ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrap `User` with quotes in annotation or use [postponed evaluation of annotations](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0563/) in case of Python 3.7.

Comment: This worked for me, however, the auto-annotate feature in Pycharm (2018.2.5) does not include the quotation marks. Bug? Pycharm bug? Python bug? Is this documented anywhere?

Comment: @jpcgt It's a PyCharm bug, it's better to file an issue https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/PY

Answer (score -1):

Ensure that you have imported the User class correctly in your module. Make sure you have the appropriate import statement at the top of your file, such as:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
```

Check if the Django framework is properly installed and accessible to PyCharm. You can verify this by running other Django-related code or checking your project's interpreter settings in PyCharm.

If PyCharm still does not recognize the User class, you can try manually specifying the module where User is defined in the type hint. Assuming your User class is defined in a module called models, you can modify your code like this:

```
class X(models.Model):
    def add_member(self, user: models.User):
        # code
```

By explicitly referencing the model's module before User, PyCharm should be able to recognize the type hint.

Comment: This answer looks like it was generated by an AI (like ChatGPT), not by an actual human being. You should be aware that [posting AI-generated output is officially **BANNED** on Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/421831). If this answer was indeed generated by an AI, then I strongly suggest you delete it before you get yourself into even bigger trouble: **WE TAKE PLAGIARISM SERIOUSLY HERE.** Please read: [Why posting GPT and ChatGPT generated answers is not currently allowed](https://stackoverflow.com/help/gpt-policy).

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).